# I am a contractor doing work for a company selling on Amazon. Can I use their MWS root credentials?

Tags: amazon-mws

From their docs...

> Important: Do Not Share Amazon MWS Access Keys
> Sharing your Amazon MWS Access Keys is a violation of Amazon’s Terms of Service. Sharing your Access Keys may result in suspension of your selling account and Access Keys.

Does this only apply to external developers who create generic applications that could be used by multiple organizations?

In my mind, I am working *as* the company, so I don't see an issue using their root credentials. However, the last thing I'd want to do is get their account in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you are employed by the company and working as full time employee, then you dont.   IF you are working as amazon developer then yes you need to have your own developer account and say your client to give access to it (ideal scenario).  Because at the end of contract you don't need more access to it and they can revoke.